Curve in chemistry
I'm trying to approach this curve but I'm having trouble placing the points better.

Please help.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=15cm, height=10cm,
        xlabel={\textbf{VOLUME DE TITRANT (VAcide)}},
        ylabel={\textbf{pH} / \textbf{quantité de moles (mol)}},
        ymin=0, ymax=10,
        xmin=0, xmax=25,
        grid=both,
        minor tick num=1,
        major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
        minor grid style={line width=.1pt,draw=gray!50},
        legend style={at={(1.05,1)},anchor=north west},
        legend cell align={left},
    ]

    % pH curve
    \addplot[thick, smooth, color=black] coordinates {
        (0, 9.2) (5, 6) (10, 5.3) (15, 3) (17.5, 2.5) (20, 3) (25, 8)
    };

    % Quantity of moles curve
    \addplot[thick, smooth, dashed, color=black] coordinates {
        (0, 0) (5, 0.5) (10, 1) (15, 1.5) (20, 2)
    };

    % Labels
    \node at (axis cs: 0, 9.2) [anchor=north east] {\textbf{Au début}};
    \node at (axis cs: 5, 6) [anchor=north west] {\textbf{H}};
    \node at (axis cs: 10, 5.3) [anchor=north west] {\textbf{Demi-équivalence}};
    \node at (axis cs: 15, 3) [anchor=north west] {\textbf{C (Volume)}};
    \node at (axis cs: 20, 3) [anchor=south west] {\textbf{Equivalence}};
    \node at (axis cs: 17.5, 2.5) [anchor=north east] {\textbf{D1}};
    \node at (axis cs: 20, 3) [anchor=north east] {\textbf{D1}};
    \node at (axis cs: 25, 8) [anchor=north west] {\textbf{D2}};
    \node at (axis cs: 25, 0) [anchor=north west] {\textbf{État final}};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

And here is the result :


Welcome. // Unfortunately your question seems to be incomplete, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/721747/curve-in-chemistry/721748?noredirect=1#comment1795582_721748 .

Here, for comparison, is an effort in Metapost, the drawing language built-in to LuaLatex.  I have drawn the curve using a series of control points instead of trying to fit a function to them -- you can do the same in Tikz using the Hobby package.  (I have assumed the OP wanted the curve in the graphic).

Here is the source.  You need to compile this with lualatex.  I have added comments to explain what's going on.  Follow the link at the top for tutorials and reference information about Metapost.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

  % unit size
  numeric u; u = 24;

  % axes
  path xx, yy;
  xx = 2 left -- 20u * right + 2 right;
  yy = 2 down -- 13u * up + 2 up;

  % curve
  path ss;
  ss = (0, 11.2) .. controls (0, 10.2) .. 
       ( 5, 9.2) .. controls (10, 8.2) .. 
       (10, 5.3) .. controls (10, 2.2) .. 
       (18, 1.6) ..  (20, 1.5);
  ss := ss scaled u;

  % draw the grid
  for x=1 upto 20:
    draw yy shifted (x*u, 0) withcolor 3/4;
  endfor
  for y=1 upto 13:
    draw xx shifted (0, y*u) withcolor 3/4;
  endfor

  % draw the D lines
  drawoptions(withcolor 1/2[2/3 blue, white]);
  path d[]; 
  d1 = (0, 13u) -- (10u, 1/2) -- (20u, 1/2); 
  d2 = origin -- (10u, 13u) -- (20u, 13u); 
  draw d1; draw d2; 
  label.urt ("$D_1$", point .85 of d1);
  label.top ("$D_1$", point 1.35 of d1);
  label.ulft("$D_2$", point .85 of d2);
  label.bot ("$D_2$", point 1.35 of d2);
  drawoptions();

  % draw central asymptote, then the curve, with key points
  draw (origin -- 5u * up) shifted point 2 of ss dashed evenly withcolor 3/4 red;
  draw ss withcolor 3/4 red;
  for i=0 upto length ss - 1:
    draw point i of ss withpen pencircle scaled 4 withcolor 3/4 red;
  endfor

  % draw the axes
  drawarrow xx scaled 1.02;
  drawarrow yy scaled 1.03;
  drawarrow yy scaled 1.03 shifted (20u, 0);

  % states
  vardef boxed_label@#(expr t, z) = 
    interim labeloffset := 8; bboxmargin := 3;
    save p; picture p; p = thelabel@#("\small " & t, z);
    unfill bbox p; draw bbox p withcolor 3/4 red; draw p;
  enddef;
  boxed_label.top("Au début",         point 0 of ss);
  boxed_label.top("Demi-équivalence", point 1 of ss shifted 18 right);
  boxed_label.rt ("Equivalence",      point 2 of ss);
  boxed_label.bot("Etat final",       point 3 of ss);

  % pH values
  for i = 1 upto 3:
    numeric y; y = ypart point i of ss;
    draw (4 left -- 1.3u * right) shifted (0, y) withcolor 3/4 red;
    label.lft(decimal (y/u), (-4, y)); 
  endfor
  label.lft("pH", (-4, 13u));

  % volumes
  for i= 1 upto 2:
    numeric x; x = xpart point i of ss;
    draw (4 down -- 1.3u * up) shifted (x, 0) withcolor 3/4 red;
    label.bot(decimal (2x/u) & "\thinspace mL", (x, -4));
  endfor
  label.llft("Volume de titrant", (20u, -4));

  % arrowed label
  z0 = (9.6u, 8.8u);
  z1 = (9.9u, 7.5u);
  ahangle := 20;
  drawarrow z0 -- z1;
  label.top("$C_1$", z0);

  % right hand axis label
  label.rt(TEX("quantité de moles (mol)") rotated 90, (20u + 4, 8u));

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}


You are close:

define a dot-style
introduce it as a node with empty text, name it
anchor your text below etc.

Keys:
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    dot/.style={circle,fill=black},
]

    % ~~~ one example: 2 steps ~~~~~~~~
    \node[dot] (H) at (axis cs: 5, 6) {};
    \node at (H.south) [anchor=north] {\textbf{H}};

Remember, the dot this way is the shape of the empty node, (H) in this case. To change its dimensions you need to adjust inner sep and minimum size in the dot-style.
You may also want to look up (and define a text-style) how to break lines in a node. Search e.g. for align=center, which is one way to do it, together with \\, like in  {this\\is broken}.

%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    dot/.style={circle,fill=black},
]
    \begin{axis}[
        width=15cm, height=10cm,
        xlabel={\textbf{VOLUME DE TITRANT (VAcide)}},
        ylabel={\textbf{pH} / \textbf{quantité de moles (mol)}},
        ymin=0, ymax=10,
        xmin=0, xmax=25,
        grid=both,
        minor tick num=1,
        major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
        minor grid style={line width=.1pt,draw=gray!50},
        legend style={at={(1.05,1)},anchor=north west},
        legend cell align={left},
    ]

    % pH curve
    \addplot[thick, smooth, color=black] coordinates {
        (0, 9.2) (5, 6) (10, 5.3) (15, 3) (17.5, 2.5) (20, 3) (25, 8)
    };

    % Quantity of moles curve
    \addplot[thick, smooth, dashed, color=black] coordinates {
        (0, 0) (5, 0.5) (10, 1) (15, 1.5) (20, 2)
    };

    % Labels
    \node at (axis cs: 0, 9.2) [anchor=north east] {\textbf{Au début}};
    
    % ~~~ one example: 2 steps ~~~~~~~~
    \node[dot] (H) at (axis cs: 5, 6) {};
    \node at (H.south) [anchor=north] {\textbf{H}};
    
    \node at (axis cs: 10, 5.3) [anchor=north west] {\textbf{Demi-équivalence}};
    \node at (axis cs: 15, 3) [anchor=north west] {\textbf{C (Volume)}};
    \node at (axis cs: 20, 3) [anchor=south west] {\textbf{Equivalence}};
    \node at (axis cs: 17.5, 2.5) [anchor=north east] {\textbf{D1}};
    \node at (axis cs: 20, 3) [anchor=north east] {\textbf{D1}};
    \node at (axis cs: 25, 8) [anchor=north west] {\textbf{D2}};
    \node at (axis cs: 25, 0) [anchor=north west] {\textbf{État final}};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Follow-up
Your data points seem to be not chosen to match the screenshot ... However, you have at least two options for better interpolation:

a) enter more data points
b) using Bezier-facilities from plain Tikz

Ad a), this will work, but will drive you crazy when applying smooth and tension.
Ad b), you can apply almost the same controls as Thruston showed, or the to appraoch specifying in and out angles.  This way pgfplots gives you grid and axes, while plain Tikz does the Bezier part.
Anyway, you need more data points. As an aside, with plain Tikz you can define coordinates on the way for easier reference later.
Adding the two linear curves is even easier this way; or you draw them vial \addplotwith the same amount of ease  ...
I commented out non-relevant parts, below.

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    dot/.style={circle,fill=black},
]
    \begin{axis}[
        width=15cm, height=10cm,
        xlabel={\textbf{VOLUME DE TITRANT (VAcide)}},
        ylabel={\textbf{pH} / \textbf{quantité de moles (mol)}},
        ymin=0, ymax=15,
        xmin=0, xmax=40,
        grid=both,
        minor tick num=1,
        major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
        minor grid style={line width=.1pt,draw=gray!50},
        legend style={at={(1.05,1)},anchor=north west},
        legend cell align={left},
    ]

%    % pH curve
%    \addplot[thick, smooth, tension=.4, color=black] coordinates {
%        ( 0, 11.2)
%        ( 1, 10.4)
%        ( 2, 10  )
%        ( 4,  9.8)
%        (10,  9.2)
%        (18,  8.3)
%       (19,  8  )
%        (20,  5.3)
%        (22,  2.2)
%        (21,  2.5)
%        (26,  1.8)
%        (36,  1.6)
%    };

    % Quantity of moles curve
%    \addplot[thick, smooth, dashed, color=black] coordinates {
%        (0, 0) (5, 0.5) (10, 1) (15, 1.5) (20, 2)
%    };


    % ~~~ just some TikZ drawing instead ~~~
    \draw   (axis cs:  0, 11.2) coordinate (A) to[out=290,in=175] 
            (axis cs: 10,  9.2) coordinate (B) to[out=00,in=90]
            (axis cs: 19.9,7.0) coordinate (C)  --
            (axis cs: 20,  5.3) coordinate (D) -- 
            (axis cs: 20.1,5.1) coordinate (E) to[out=270, in=180]
            (axis cs: 36,  1.6 )coordinate (F) 
            ;
            
    % ~~~ dots ~~~~~
    \node[dot] at (B) {};
    \node[dot] at (D) {};
    
    % ~~~ labels ~~~
    \node[anchor=north,yshift=-3mm] at (B) {Text};
    \node[anchor=west, xshift= 3mm]  at (D) {Equivalence};

%    % Labels
%    \node at (axis cs: 0, 9.2) [anchor=north east] {\textbf{Au début}};
%    
%    % ~~~ one example: 2 steps ~~~~~~~~
%    \node[dot] (H) at (axis cs: 5, 6) {};
%    \node at (H.south) [anchor=north] {\textbf{H}};
%    
%    \node at (axis cs: 10, 5.3) [anchor=north west] {\textbf{Demi-équivalence}};
%    \node at (axis cs: 15, 3) [anchor=north west] {\textbf{C (Volume)}};
%    \node at (axis cs: 20, 3) [anchor=south west] {\textbf{Equivalence}};
%    \node at (axis cs: 17.5, 2.5) [anchor=north east] {\textbf{D1}};
%    \node at (axis cs: 20, 3) [anchor=north east] {\textbf{D1}};
%    \node at (axis cs: 25, 8) [anchor=north west] {\textbf{D2}};
%    \node at (axis cs: 25, 0) [anchor=north west] {\textbf{État final}};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


I want to reproduce exactly the same curve as in the initial image.

Ok, so you need some interpolation. // Please add your comments remark to your question, to make it clearer. Thank you

Please see my follow-up. // Please correct your question, as indicated. // Please be more precise with your data next time. Thank you
